# Can Time Machine backup two HDDs to Time Capsule?

Tags: time-machine, backup, time-capsule

I have two physical harddrives in my Mac.  One is an SSD with the OS and apps.  The other is a 1TB HDD for media. Can I setup time machine to backup both drives to time capsule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, by default Time Machine will backup all internal HDD's whether they are SSD or not. Just make sure your time capsule is big enough.

Comment: +1. Time Machine will also backup ***external*** drives plugged in to your Mac (except the Time Machine drive, naturally).